# jQuery each toggleClass and append

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I wanted to make a dropdown for the main Categories.

`html`

```
<ul class="product-categories">
 <li class="cat-item cat-item-16 cat-parent"><a href="#">Clothing</a>
 <ul class="children">
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-19"><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-18"><a href="#">Hoodies</a></li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-17"><a href="#">Tshirts</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>


 <li class="cat-item cat-item-15 cat-parent"><a href="#">Uncategorized</a>
  <ul class="children">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-39"><a href="#">Example</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-40"><a href="#">example2</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

`CSS`

```
ul.children {
    display: none; 
}
ul.children.ok {
    display: block; 
}
```

`jQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cat-parent').each( function( index, element ){
    $(this).append("<span style='float:right;cursor:pointer' class='show'>&#8595;</span>");
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).find('ul.children').toggleClass('ok');
    });
  });
});
```

But I wanted to do this not when I clicked on the categories, but when I created an arrow span on the right and clicked on it, but I couldn't do it, where am I going wrong?

You can check the demo available below.

https://jsfiddle.net/justfeel/k5qa6j21/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that when you use `.append` it appears after the children `ul` *and* the ul's `li` elements, so moves down when you expand.

As you're using `float:right` you can put your arrow *before* the `ul` and it will appear in the correct place and then not move.

```
$(this).prepend("<span
```

Updated snippet (and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxukLzpt/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cat-parent').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).prepend("<span style='float:right;cursor:pointer' class='show'>&#8595;</span>");
    $(this).click(function() {
      $(this).find('ul.children').toggleClass('ok');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
ul.children {
  display: none;
}

ul.children.ok {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="product-categories">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-16 cat-parent"><a href="#">Clothing</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-19"><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-18"><a href="#">Hoodies</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-17"><a href="#">Tshirts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>


  <li class="cat-item cat-item-15 cat-parent"><a href="#">Uncategorized</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-39"><a href="#">Example</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-40"><a href="#">example2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Note that you don't need to each `.each` (for the code provided) as many/most of jquery's operations work on the entire collection:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cat-parent')
    .prepend("<span style='float:right;cursor:pointer' class='show'>&#8595;</span>")
    .click(function() {
        $(this).find('ul.children').toggleClass('ok');
    });
});
```

```css
ul.children {
  display: none;
}

ul.children.ok {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="product-categories">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-16 cat-parent"><a href="#">Clothing</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-19"><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-18"><a href="#">Hoodies</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-17"><a href="#">Tshirts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>


  <li class="cat-item cat-item-15 cat-parent"><a href="#">Uncategorized</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-39"><a href="#">Example</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-40"><a href="#">example2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```